# How to route a POJO through activemq with camel

Tags: routes, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I'm fairly new to camel and trying to figure some things out. Currently I have a route that sends a POJO to activemq and then later I receieve that message from activemq, but the body of the message is null. If I skip the activemq portion of the route it works no problem.

How can I route my POJO through activemq without serializing it?

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up serializing my objects and it worked fine.